# Difference between "const" and "Vue.component"

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm really new to the Vue framework and constantly stalling at the basics. Currently I'm stuck with following scenario.

I create/build reusable components this way below:

```
Vue.component('SomeReusableComponent', {
    props: [ ... ],
    template: `
        <Some HTML>
    `
})
```

But I also saw other people creating/building components like this:

```
const SomeReusableComponent = {
    props: [ ... ],
    template:`
        <Some HTML>
    `
}
```

What is the difference between the two? What is each use case? I mean, I can also attach a `Vue.component` to a `const` and it will basically become the same, or not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vue component is nothing but a plain javascript object containing the components options like `data`, `template`, `computed` etc as its properties.

> What is the difference between the two?

`Vue.component(componentName, componentOptions)` creates a global component. The component created like this can be used anyehere without registering it.

For example:
Vue.component('global-comp', {template: 'This is global component')

The above created component can be used directly as:

```
//another-component
  <div>
    <global-comp></global-comp>
  </div>
```

Now the other type of component.

As said above a component is nothing but a plain object

For example:

```
const MyComponent ={
    template: '<div>My {{text}} component</div>',
    data(){
      return{
        text: 'awesome'
      }
    }
  }
```

To use the above component in another component you need to register it under `components` option as below

```
//another component
  <div>
    <my-component></my-component>
  </div>

  <script>
    //another component
    export default{
      name: 'Another',
      //this is required to register my-component if 
      //it is not global i.e not defined using Vue.component()
      components:{
        'my-component': MyComponent
      }
    }
  </script>
```

**Note:**

- You do not want to register every component globally as it would
  pollute the global namespace.
- You do not need every component used at multiple places.
- In the future when you learn to lazy load your component, you do not want a component which the user might not need in initial bundle and increase its size

Docs- [Component Registration](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html)

Comment: Thanks for this clarifying answer. May I ask you for what exactly the second example with "export" is useful?

Comment: It just how a component looks if you yuse a bundler like webpack or create a vue project using vue-cli which interna,ly uses webpack

Comment: Oh, more complex stuff... Hopefully I will get to that soon. Thanks again.

Comment: @Fusseldieb wishing you good luck and hope you get there.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

1. `Vue.component` function registers component for global usage. So if you registered `Vue.component('my-awesome-component', { /* params */ })` you can use `<my-awesome-component>` in  any another component template.
2. When you just declare object like your second example with `const` you will have to register this component some how further with `Vue.component` function as well or **in parent component** `components` **section** (to use locally in parent component only).

   ```
   //in parent component
   import MyAwesomeComponent from "./my-awesome-component";

   export default {
   ...
       components: { MyAwesomeComponent }
   ...
   }
   ```